# How to add frame number "5/12"-style to theme template?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I have a long title, therefore I've chosen [`Amsterdam` theme](http://latex.simon04.net/) for the `beamer` package. However, I need to also show the frame number "frame/fromTotalFrames" style.

How can I add the frame-no. on the left hand side of the footer, while centering the title?

The theme code:

```
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\mode
<all>
```

Some example frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Amsterdam} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{General Theory of Relativity is a long Title\\
for normal Footers}
\author{Albert Einstein}
\date{April 2, 1922}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

%%%
\section[Overview]{}
%\subsection{Layout}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here comes the Figure
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%\subsection{Agenda}
\frame{\tableofcontents}
%%%


%%%
\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame}{Theory is practical}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here come the reasons
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%%%


%%%
\section[Review]{Review of casual theory}
\subsection{classic Theories}
\begin{frame}{Which is Eligible?}
Newton, Lagrange, etc.
\end{frame}

\section[Review]{Review of casual theory}
\subsection{classic Theories}
\begin{frame}{Which is Eligible?}
Goethe, Dasgupta etc.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And suppressing the author?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you! Ideally without suppressing the Author.

Comment: And then, where the author should go? You say the title should be centered and the frame numbers to the left. Where do you want the author to appear?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For me the code sets the Author on the RIGHT hand side. The Title could be in the middle, while the frames ideally on the LEFT hand side.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine the `footline` template appropriately; in the following code I used three `beamercolorbox`es; one for the author, another one for the title, and the third one for the frame numbers; feel free to adjust the widths according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Amsterdam} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{General Theory of Relativity is a long Title\\
for normal Footers}
\author{Albert Einstein}
\date{April 2, 1922}

\makeatletter
  \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{myminiframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,center]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

%%%
\section[Overview]{}
%\subsection{Layout}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here comes the Figure
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%\subsection{Agenda}
\frame{\tableofcontents}
%%%


%%%
\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame}{Theory is practical}
\begin{itemize}
\item Here come the reasons
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%%%


%%%
\section[Review]{Review of casual theory}
\subsection{classic Theories}
\begin{frame}{Which is Eligible?}
Newton, Lagrange, etc.
\end{frame}

\section[Review]{Review of casual theory}
\subsection{classic Theories}
\begin{frame}{Which is Eligible?}
Goethe, Dasgupta etc.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the footline:

[image]

Of course, you can place the relevant code:

```
  \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{myminiframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,center]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.75\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
```

in the file `beamerthemeAmsterdam.sty` instead of in your `.tex` file (in the .sty file you don't use `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`).

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the Author is now on the wrong (left), instead of right. Similarly the frame-no. Can you please comment the  code where the change is required. I've tried for 1h and did not accomplished to get a result without an error. Maybe also others could profit from it. Thank you much for your help. :)

Comment: @alex my bad. I swapped the positions. I've edited my answer with the desired order. All you need to do is to change the order of the `beamercolorbox`es. I can add some comments to the code, but tomorrow (I'm tired and it's bed time here).